# Windows 10 - how to prevent Microsoft Text Input Application from starting?

Tags: windows-10, process, on-screen-keyboard, windows-10-v20h2

I Am trying to prevent **Microsoft Text Input Application** from starting. Process name: **"TextInputHost.exe"**. I know it is behind an on-screen keyboard. But I don't use this! It starts nevertheless, after a Windows startup. I am on Windows 10 Pro x64 20H2, but this is bothering me a long time!

**Goal:** is to disable it properly, as you can rename the folder - but it generates Errors in Event Viewer.

**What I tried:**

**First I tried to rename** **"MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy"** by adding **.bak** at the end. Which prevents a startup. However this is not an optimal way to disable applications in Windows. It could create some problems! I Am confident this could be disabled by editing some hidden registry value. Problem is to find it!

As I had a similar problem with "GameBarPresenceWriter.exe". It was starting at any game launch. Even GameDVR and Gamebar were disabled in every possible location! And then I found some hidden registry key on minitool.com. Which allowed me to disable it!

**I also tried:**

- startup of "**TabletInputService**" is disabled!
- all settings in pen & ink are disabled
- inking and typing is disabled
- use on-screen keyboard is disabled

Comment: Not sure if this is same as your case but there is an old article mentioned that if users are getting touch keyboard pop-up, the workaround is to turn off the Windows Mixed Reality: https://www.windowslatest.com/2017/10/19/fix-touch-keyboard-pop-up-at-login-windows-10/

Comment: I don't have touch keyboard showing up, nor installed Windows Mixed Reality. I just want to prevent this process from running!

Comment: MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy - I take it this is the subfolder of C:\Windows\SystemApps?

Answer (score 8):

Following solution is aimed at **build** **1903**! On newer builds it will generate DCOM error 10001. This can be fixed by disabling startup of "InputService" in DCOMcnfg and denying all its permissions. **However it is not recommended to edit anything in DCOMcnfg.exe!!!**


**The solution:** Open **TaskManager**, click on the process in question in the Process tab, expand and right click/Details to find out its exact name (differs per system)!

If **MicrosoftTextInputApplication's** process is called **"TextInputHost.exe"** paste this into elevated CMD:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\TextInputHost.exe" /v Debugger /d "%SystemRoot%\system32\systray.exe" /f
taskkill /im "TextInputHost.exe" /t /f
echo done
```

If it is called **"InputApp.exe"**  paste this:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp.exe" /v Debugger /d "%SystemRoot%\system32\systray.exe" /f
taskkill /im "WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp.exe" /t /f 
echo done
```

To undone changes (change name to your process name):

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp.exe" /v Debugger /f
echo done
```

**Source:** https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/133209-microsoft-text-input-application-inicio-start-english-processes-3.html?133209=#post2125555

**DCOM Event ID 10001 general description:**

```
Unable to start a DCOM Server: MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.551.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy!InputApp as Unavailable/Unavailable. The error:
"2147942402"
Happened while starting this command:
"C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\InputApp\TextInputHost.exe" -ServerName:InputApp.AppX9jnwykgrccxc8by3hsrsh07r423xzvav.mca
```

For more details: https://pastebin.com/aNWvZmCh

**What I did I do to solve DCOM error:** 
I disabled startup and denied all permissions for "InputService" APPID = {730BFCEC-E4BF-4D3A-9FBB-01DD132467A4} in DCOMcnfg.exe [Tutorial](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50926.windows-component-services-troubleshooting-unable-to-edit-dcom-security-permissions.aspx)

You have to also rename the folder: **"MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy"** by putting at the end of its name .bak! Located in: **C:\Windows\SystemApps**

**PS:** **If anyone has a solution how to prevent "TextInputHost.exe" from starting safely without generating errors and editing DCOMcnfg.exe that would be great!**

Comment: Thank you for the precise -- and completely accurate -- instructions for disabling this piece of bloatware and getting rid of the DCOM errors.

Comment: FWIW, This will also disable that handy little emoji popup _(Win+.)_ along w/ modern touch keyboard. Old OSK still works.

Comment: When I click on properties I see  **MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy**. It seems right clicking on this properties shows this as a dir not a service or application.